# Angular: service.setData is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

Why angular says me that setData is not a function?

```
angular.module('mdl').factory('DataService', ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope',
    function ($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope) {
        return {
            setData: function (data) {
                $rootScope.data = data;
            },
        };
    }
]);
```

Here is my controller which calls `setData`.

```
angular.module('mdl').controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', 'DataService',
function($scope, $http, $location, DataService) {

    $scope.getData = function (id) {
        $http.post('/rest/data/get', id)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                DataService.setData(data);
                $location.path('/main');
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });
    };
}
```

]);

Comment: can you see the code where you call your setData ?

Comment: in  controller use DataService.setData or your DataService object name

Comment: @MathieuBertin added controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem on dependencies injection, you are declaring 6 items and in your function you have 5 items. And the missing is DataService.

```
['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', 'DataService',
function($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope /*Missing*/, DataService) {
…
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're declaring a function in service you should pass a `this` reference to function. You could do it like too

```
angular.module('mdl').factory('DataService', ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope',
    function ($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope) {

            this.setData: function (data) {
                return data;
            }

    }
]);
```

and in controller make this factory as a dependency and call factory's function like

```
$scope.data = DataService.setData();
```

You should not use `$rootScope`. You should use above call instead

Comment: But this for service, and I am using factory.
I need to use `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `DataService.setData(data);` with `LoginService.setData(data);` in your controller, as you have renamed the factory when passed in as a parameter.