# Angular 'is not a function' caused by missing import?

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror

Getting an 'is not a function' in Angular 7 / typescript 3-ish, using an EventEmitter.  Much has been written ([a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function) [b](https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/x-is-not-a-function-typeerror)) about this error, but very few upvotes for answers ([a](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-reason-for-error-typeerror-_co-onclick-is-not-a-function-angular-2) [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193540/inline-template11-caused-by-self-context-onsubmit-is-not-a-function-getting-e) [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343011/angular-rxjs-observable-timer-is-not-a-function-with-import) [d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486774/crypto-randombytes-is-not-a-function-in-angular) [e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595371/angular-service-setdata-is-not-a-function) [f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823978/angular-ionic-interval-is-not-a-function) ).  I'm almost there, but need some help finishing this off.

Here is one stackblitz [*with*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isnotfunction) the error.
...and a similar one [*without*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/emit-child-to-parent) the error.

The only difference seems to be that with the error, my event emitter and receiver are in sibling folders.  In the one that works, the event receiver is in a parent folder and the emitter is in a child folder.

It seems like some kind of an import/module tweak is required to fix the broken one, but I can't seem to get it.
Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You've done some research, but what is the question here? This is a very broad and general JavaScript error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your `parent.component.ts` file.
You named function as `parentListner` in ts file but used `parentListener` in html file.

Answer (score 2):

In your parent ts. You have a function:

```
parentListner($event) {
    this.childMessage = $event
 }
```

While in html you are calling:

```
<app-child (childEvent)="parentListener($event)"></app-child>
```

Names have to be the same.